# Onclick not working properly

Tags: java, android

I need to click once to implement the methods in Onclick but the problem here that in counter it won't count until i click button constantly and i have several check conditions that print text to the user if true these texts don't show up until i click the button one more time , how to handle that issue ? i want the button to be clicked once then all the code inside Onclick implemented properly

```
 Life.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
             public void onClick(View v)
             {       counterLife();
                 Help.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 Reset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // other code
```

.............

```
void counterLife() //To count  
{

        if (a && T2 ==0 && T3 == 0) 
        {
          if(countLife == 6)  
               { //code 
                     text.setText("You Completed 6 Lives ");
                                }

               else
               countLife ++ ;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first time you click you should use the OnFocusChangeListener to get the event.

After foucus is on the View all extra clicks will invoke the OnClickListener event.

You can also do this:

```
setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // call your onclick method
            }
        }
    });
```